# CSR: can SP.ClientContext be used in OnPostRender?

Tags: client-side-rendering

Seems like SP.ClientContext is not yet ready in the OnPostRender function

I could add a delay, but would like to update some List content in the OnPostRender

I get a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined
```

Weird thing is.. it displays the above **two** lines in the SharePoint window, so it seems its the `RegisterTemplateOverrides` returning content

[image]

#### minimal CSR file `s1.js` :

```
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {
      function init() {
        var overrides = {Templates: {Fields: {}}};
        overrides.Templates.OnPostRender=function(){
          var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrides);
      }
      var csrfile = "~siteCollection/Style Library/s1.js";
      if (console) console.info(csrfile);
      RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens(csrfile), init);
      init();
    });
```

Comment: Would _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('init()'); help ? Instead of calling init() directly ?

Comment: Weird, OnPostRender seems to fire **twice**, one time before the ``_spBodyOnLoadFunction``, and again after. This is alfa code, I'll understand more and come back after I have played with it for some days. For now I set a semaphore in the OnLoadFunction to only proces code in the last OnPostRender

Comment: why not just wrap your code into `SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() { ... })`?

Comment: Good to see you online again, Andrey. You are correct, loading sp.js asap should work (I refactored my code to REST so worked around it in a different way) Rewrite your comment as an Answer and we can close this topic (and you stay ahead of me with them points ;-)